# Javascript object bool field magically changes value

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I stumbled upon a strange behaviour of Javascript objects. boolean fields seem to always get "true" value and it can never be changed.

I'm preparing simple pagination directive with message popup.

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-class="{active: button.isCurrent}">
    <a ng-click="button.click()" popover-template="'popover.html'" popover-placement="bottom" popover-is-open="button.showPageSelector" href="#">{{page.text}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I receive response from server, I create buttons using following script in .js:

```
// visiblePages is an array of Numbers
function buildPagination(scope, visiblePages) {
  scope.buttons = visiblePages.map(function (number) {
    return {
      text: number.toString(),
      isCurrent: number === scope.currentPage,
      showPageSelector: false,
      click: function () {
        if (this.isCurrent) {
          this.showPageSelector = !(this.showPageSelector);
        }
      }
    };
  });
}
```

As you can see, popup visibility is controlled by `showPageSelector` field of button object. Now, I just want to show tooltip if current page is clicked, but it doesn't show up. I turned on debugger and set breakpoint on `click` function. it seems that `showPageSelector` was set to `true`. The problem is that `showPageSelector` is used only in these 3 lines and I expected it to be `false`. And each time I click pagination I get same result - assignement doesn't change the value.

Why is that? Is it an Angular bug or problem in Javascript? Problem exists on both Firefox 61.0.2 and Chrome 67.0.3396.99, so I guess it's not a problem with browser

Comment: `isCurrent` will never change, since you set it to true or false when you create the buttons array.  I guess you want to execute a function there to determine whether it's the current page at the point you click the button.  Because of that, you're never running the code that changes the value of `this.showPageSelector`.  Also, I'm not sure about the scoping of `this` inside that click function.

Comment: `isCurrent` should not change - I want to rebuild paginator each time I receive response from server. The toggling code runs properly - except that `showPageSelector` is always `true` at the beginning of `click` function and `false` at the end of function.

Comment: I also checked `this` variable, but it's correct object. I also changed `text` field and this change persists, so I receive same instance of object

Comment: I'm not sure what it is then, but bool values definitely work in Javascript.  The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, thanks for notification about MCV. I created one in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3k4ovOdrZo7bBW1dLr2C?p=preview) and it works as I expected. Looks like the problem lies in another part of my project